# How change coordinate of flame?

Tags: android

Hi I am working on OpenGL and using gl.glOrthofo but it is always drawing in the lower left but I want to draw on randomly on screen.

[image: Here's what I'm getting]

I am using this code

```
gl.glShadeModel(GL11.GL_FLAT);//FLAT
gl.glFrontFace(GL11.GL_CCW);

gl.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

gl.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
gl.glPushMatrix();
gl.glLoadIdentity();
//left,right,bottom,top,znear,zfar
gl.glOrthof(0.0, surfaceWidth,0.0f,surfaceHeight , 0.0f, 1.0f);//if changing
                                                        //then produce error
gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
gl.glPushMatrix();
gl.glLoadIdentity();

glInited = false;
```

As shown in the image the fire flame is always draw in lower left on screen. Please guide me!

Comment: @RajaReddyP Hi - you tried to edit this to swap `surfaceHeight` to be the first parameter of `gl.glOrthof()`. If you think that's the problem then please post an answer or comment rather than editing the question - thanks!

Comment: Hi- when I pass  gl.glOrthof( surfaceHeight, surfaceWidth,0.0f,0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); produce stop unexcepted exception so plz guide me...

Comment: I m adding whole code of produce fire flame please help me How I can render its flame on screen randomally